# Infinite scrolling with React with scrollTo capability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I would like to implement in React infinite scrolling with scrolling to specific element capability. But in my case the height of the elements are dynamic + user can resize the panel, where the list is hosting, affecting the height of each item.

So, how can I calculate the size of my list items efficiently and where to plugin this logic in React?
At the moment I am trying to use [React List](https://github.com/orgsync/react-list) component which provides 
itemSizeGetter callback where I can define the logic for size calculation. My original idea was to render individual element to the hidden div (so that the styles are applied), ask browser for the size and then remove the element. But if I call ReactDOM.render(...) inside this method React complains that I cannot call render inside the render method.